# Adapter won't run on a real device

Tags: android

The same code that displays the lists running on the emulator doesn't run on the mobile (Motorola Milestone). I'm using the same android platform (2.1-update).

### Inbox Code

```
private ArrayList<EmailModel> email_list;


private EmailAdapter email_adapter;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  try {
   this.email_list = populate_list();
   email_adapter = new EmailAdapter(this, email_list);
   setListAdapter(email_adapter);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.v("Inbox", "Adapting Problem: " + e.toString());
  }
 }
```

### EmailAdapter Code

```
public class EmailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



private ArrayList<EmailModel> elements;
private Context c;

public EmailAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<EmailModel> Emails) {

 this.elements = Emails;
    this.c = c;
}
public int getCount() {

    return elements.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return elements.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int id) {

    return id;
}

public void Remove(int id) {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void Add(EmailModel email) {

 this.elements.add(email);

 notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LinearLayout rowLayout;
    EmailModel email = elements.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
     rowLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.inbox_item, parent, false); 
    } else {
        rowLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

 TextView subject_textview = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.subject_textview);
 subject_textview.setText(email.getSubject());

 String body_hint = " - " + email.getBodyHint();

 TextView bodyhint_textview = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.body_hint_textview);
 bodyhint_textview.setText(body_hint);


 String sender_name = get_sender_name(email.getSender());

 TextView sender_name_textview = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.sender_textview);
 sender_name_textview.setText(sender_name);

 TextView date_time_textview = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.date_time_textview); 
 date_time_textview.setText(email.getTime());


    return rowLayout;
}

private String get_sender_name(String from) {

 String[] sender = from.split("<");


String sender_name;

  try {
   sender_name = sender[0];
  } catch (Exception e) {
   sender_name = sender[1];
  }
  return sender_name;
    }}
```

### exception output

> 07-16 13:15:21.190: VERBOSE/Inbox(429): Adapting Problem: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

### Stack Trace

> 07-16 14:00:49.690: WARN/System.err(703): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>   07-16 14:00:49.698: WARN/System.err(703):     at com.anubis.mail.Inbox.populate_list(Inbox.java:237)
>   07-16 14:00:49.698: WARN/System.err(703):     at com.anubis.mail.Inbox.onCreate(Inbox.java:69)
>   07-16 14:00:49.698: WARN/System.err(703):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   07-16 14:00:49.698: WARN/System.err(703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   07-16 14:00:49.706: WARN/System.err(703):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I'd suggest adding `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch statement so you get more debugging information (and, of course, a stack trace).

Comment: How are you getting the data in? Do you have mock data in the `populate_list()` method? And have you tried debugging with the device and tracing through your code?

Comment: @Dave: Ok i added the stack track.
@Pontus: populate_list() -> it gets list of emails. loops over each message and extract it into type ArrayList<EmailModel> and return the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace tells us that this Exception is occuring on line 237 of `Inbox.java` in your method `populate_list()`. This is not an issue with your adaptor. Since you've not provided the source code for `populate_list` method, we can't tell you precisely what the issue is.

So, look at line 237 of `Inbox.java`!

Answer (score 0):

I would place logging into the get_sender_name function. It doesn't make much sense to me that their could be an error with  `sender_name = sender[0];` but no error with `sender_name = sender[1];`.

Additionally you should use `Log.e` for errors instead of `Log.v`. `Log.v` is to communicate information that isn't critical but just describes how your program is running.

Comment: The input is something like this "Any Name <email@domain.com>". If there is no name it will return the email. and thanks for the tip.

Comment: No, it won't. It will just return an empty String.